# BigTIFF support in libraries?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, arcgis-platform

What is the level of support for BigTIFF in image processing libraries?

GDAL supports this functionality so long as you're building against libtiff4(beta), and I would assume most open source C libraries would as well, since I assume most of them build against either libtiff or GDAL directly.

Does ESRI software support bigtiff?

Does Java software support bigtiff (presumably through Java Advanced Imaging)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a partial answer:

- [ESRI ArcGIS Server 9.4](http://www.ntlis.nt.gov.au/forum/ntlis_documents/whats-new-in-arcgis-9.4-ozri-conference-darwin)
- [ESRI ArcGIS Desktop 10](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/imagery/archive/2010/06/30/New-supported-Raster-Formats-at-ArcGIS-10.0.aspx)
- Java support through an [experimental extension](http://geo-solutions.blogspot.com/2010/04/bigtiff-support-in-geotoolsgeoserver.html) to [ImageIO-Ext](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GEOTOOLS/ImageIO-EXT+GDAL)